# How to use GETURL in the class (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I use this code but after publish when I open my file automatically 2 internet browser (www.example.com) are open

```
package {

    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    public class bAEForm extends SimpleButton {

        public function bAEForm() {
            var url:String = "http://www.google.com";
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
            variables.exampleUserLabel = "guest";
            request.data = variables;
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            navigateToURL(request);
        }
    }
}
```

I want, when I press my button then inter browser (www.example.com) should be open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to navigate to URL when the button is clicked you code should something like this:

```
package {

    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class bAEForm extends SimpleButton {

        public function bAEForm() {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        }

        private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            var url:String = "http://www.google.com";
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
            variables.exampleUserLabel = "guest";
            request.data = variables;
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            navigateToURL(request);
        }
    }
}
```

You can't use navigateToURL function in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem :

You don't want the browsers to be already open but on click of some button.

If that is the case, Currently `navigateToURL(request);` is in the constructor of **bAEForm** class.

Move it into a click event, Something like this :

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK, 

          function(e) { navigateToURL(request); }, false,0,true);
```

where **myButton** is the button instance on click of which you want the browser to open.